# Customizing Toolbar background gradient color when VCL Themes are enabled

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I want Toolbar to show custom gradient color that I set at design time when VCL Themes are enabled.
I have used a TToolbar component and I have applied VCL themes to my project. As a result the Toolbar is not showing the gradient color which I have set, but it shows the theme color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable *seClient* in the *StyleElements* property of the Toolbar.